# Why don't the TLS1.3 cipher suites mention the key exchange and digital signature algorithm in names?

Tags: tls, dsa, ciphersuite

Does it mean both RSA and ECDSA certificates can be used with the same cipher suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. TLS 1.3's cipher suites only specify its symmetric AEAD and hash algorithms. The signature algorithms are specified separately. Several (asymmetric) signature schemes can be used with the same cipher suite.